# Actionscript 2.0 Email form LoadVars with ashx .net handler

Tags: asp.net, email, actionscript-2

I have a flash as 2.0 file that i need to send emails via an asp handler.  First off, is this possible?  Second, if it is, how do i get the return to have a status=true?

the .net codebehind

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //E-Mail Method

        string response = "sent=success";

        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(context.Request.QueryString["Email"].ToString(), context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString());
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("emailInbox@site.com", "Goons");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        message.Subject = context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString() + " sent you a message from the website.";
        message.Body = context.Request.QueryString["Msg"].ToString();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.grassrootsdm.com");
        // Include credentials if the server requires them.
        NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential("mailsenderemail","password");
        client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;

        try {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            response = ex.ToString();
        }

        context.Response.Write(response);
    }
```

the actionscript

```
if (i == 0) {
    sendVars.Name = fieldName.field.text;
    sendVars.Email = fieldEmail.field.text;
    sendVars.Msg = fieldMsg.field.text;
    sendVars.sendAndLoad("http://www.grassrootsdm.com/WebService/EmailHandler.ashx", statusVars, "POST");
    statusMsg.text = "Sending...";
    statusVars.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {

        if (success) {
            if (statusVars.sent == "success") {
                clearForm();
                statusMsg.text = "Message sent";
            }
        } else {
            statusMsg.text = "Error!";
        }
        clearInterval(clearStatus);
        clearStatus = setInterval(clearStatusInt, 3000);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Read the important notes at the bottom of each codes pertain to sending and retrieving data from flash to .net page. Explanation of the code is in the comment inside the code.

**Flash Part (Action Script 2)**

```
//function to send invoke .net page to send email
//use other control/button to call this function
//important: in order for the 'onLoad' event to work correctly, this function has to be 'Void'
function sendMail():Void
{
    //show status
    statusMsg.text = "Sending...";

    //create LoadVars object
    var lv_in:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    var lv_out:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

    //set onLoad event
    lv_in.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
    {
        //if success, meaning data has received from .net page, run this code
        if (success)
        {
            //lv_in.sent is used to parsed out message/data from .Net page
            statusMsg.text = "Message sent!" + lv_in.sent;
        }
        //if fail, run this code
        else
        {
            statusMsg.text = "Error!";
        }
    }

    //begin invoke .net page to send email
    lv_out.sendAndLoad("SendMail.aspx", lv_in, "POST");
}
```

**Important note:**
The function that contain **onLoad** event, in this case **sendMail** function, has to be **Void** function, meaning it's not returning value. If this function return value, what happen is the function will be executed all the way without waiting for the data for the return data from .net page, thus the **onLoad** event will not be set properly.

**.Net Part**

I copied the OP's .Net code so assuming this code works when sending email.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //E-Mail Method        
    string response = "sent=Success&";
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(context.Request.QueryString["Email"].ToString(), context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString()); 
    MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("emailInbox@site.com", "Goons"); 
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress); 
    message.Subject = context.Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString() + " sent you a message from the website."; 
    message.Body = context.Request.QueryString["Msg"].ToString();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.grassrootsdm.com");

    // Include credentials if the server requires them. 
    NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential("mailsenderemail","password"); 
    client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo; 
    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }      
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = ex.ToString();
    }

    context.Response.Write(response);
}
```

**Important note:**
The only thing I changed from the OP's .Net code is the response message. It was originally "sent=success" which I changed to "sent=success&".
The reason for this is, if you want action script to parse the posted message/data from .Net, it will stop at **&** symbol, thus leave the rest of the message alone and only get the message under *sent* variable.